# Не отображаеться изображения

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap

картинка содержиться по адресу D:\Users\MAestro\Desktop\RapterGame.com\RapterGames\shop\static\shop\interfaceImage

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

product.html тут должно появляться изображения

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}


    <div class="row centered">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">

              <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ object.image.url }}"/></p>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <a href="{{object.upload}}"> <img src="{% static 'shop/interfaceImage/button_download.png' %}" ></a>

               <h2> {{object.story|safe|linebreaks}} </h2>

          </div>
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col"> <center>Название</center></th>
                <th scope="col">Продолжительность</th>
                <th scope="col">Языки</th>
                <th scope="col">Требования</th>
                <th scope="col">Места на диске</th>
                <th scope="col">Требования VM</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
           <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td><h4> {{object.title}} </h4></td>
               <td><h4> {{object.time}} </h4></td>
               <td><h4> {{object.langueges}} </h4></td>
               <td><h4> {{object.demand}} </h4></td>
               <td><h4> {{object.memory}} </h4></td>
               <td><h4> {{object.VirtualM}} </h4></td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



{% endblock %}
```

wrapper.html самый главный файл на всякий случай

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="witdh=device, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Rapter</title>
      {% load staticfiles %}

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}"type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <script>

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

<!-- Шапка -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            <a href="https://google.com"> <img src="{% static 'MainPage/image/RapterLogo.png' %}" ></a>

        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

          <li class="li"><a href="/news/">Главная</a></li>
          <li class="li"><a href="/shop/">Игры</a></li>
          <li class="li"><a href="/">Товары</a></li>
          <li class="li"><a href="/">О нас</a></li>

          <li id="Buttons"><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Enter">Войти</button>
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Register">Зарегестрироваться</button></li>


        </ul>

        </ul>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


    <div id="headrwrap">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row centered">
          <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset">


            <div class="container">
            {% block content %}

            {% endblock %}

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

<!-- Кнопка Войти -->

    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="Enter">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="Entered">

          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>

          <h1 class="centered">Войти</h1>

          <h3 class="EnterText">Введите Логин или E-mail</h3>
          <input type="text" class="form-control centered" placeholder="Email or Login">


          <h3 class="EnterText">Введите Пороль</h3>
          <input type="password" class="form-control centered" placeholder="password" >

          <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="EnterButton">Войти</button>

          <a href="#" id="enterVK"> <img src="{% static 'MainPage/image/enterVk.png' %}" > </a>
          <br>

          <a href="#" id="ForgetPasswords" > Забыли пароль</a>


        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
<!-- Кнопка Войти -->


<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="Register">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" id="Entered">
      <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
      <h1 class="centered">Регестрация</h1>
      <h3 class="EnterText">Введите Логин или E-mail</h3>
      <input type="text" class="form-control centered" placeholder="Email or Login">
      <h3 class="EnterText">Введите Пороль</h3>
      <input type="password" class="form-control centered" placeholder="password" >
      <h3 class="EnterText">Повторите пороль Пороль</h3>
      <input type="password" class="form-control centered" placeholder="password" >
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="RegisterButton">Зарегестрироваться</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/main.js">
</script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ object.image.url }}" просто src="{{ object.image.url }}"

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, какое именно изображение у Вас не отображается (или оба?). Также, буду признателен, если Вы приведёте структуру приложения.

Comment: <a href="{{object.upload}}"> <img src="{% static 'shop/interfaceImage/button_download.png' %}" ></a> вот это